# Can't create proper function in swift ("if" or maybe "while")

Tags: swift, string, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

Trying to make a simple app that shows current date in format "dd MMMM" and who exactly have a birthday today.

With the 1 part there is no any problem. Also i have a bank of tuples with data, for ex:    `var friend1 = ("John Black", "02 March")`

So with one tuple i can make smth like that:

```
if friend1.1 == currentDay() {
print(friend1.0)}
else {
print("No match")}
```

But when i have a dozen of tuples i don't want to check every one of them personally, how can i make it more "automated"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your tuples in an array then you can apply a filter to that array using a high order function and perform some action for all types that matches.

```
 var array = [("John Black", "02 March")), ("John White", "27 July")]

 array.filter( {$0.1 == currentDay()} ).forEach { print($0.0) }
```

The above code will filter the array on tuples that matches `currentDay()` and then for each match print the name

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about Arrays but filters in arrays is a new information to me, need to check documentation and ect. But at least i know where to look! Thanks again!

Comment: @VarikashNikolay http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_array_enumeration_and_transformation

Comment: `{$0.1 == currentDay()}` can also be written as `{$1 == currentDay()}`